# access images that i have been uploaded into tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to retrieve  pictures that i have been stored in my tomcat server, and i want to display these images in my web page, but i don't how i can reach or access them.
so how i can make this

```
 // upload code from my netbeans project
                                     File f = new File("images/" + name + ".png");
                                     OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
                                     int read;
                                     byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                                     while ((read = inp.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                                     outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);

                                     }
```

`jsp page <img src="?">`

Comment: the images stored in bin folder in tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

- You shouldn't upload to "the current directory", e.g. tomcat's bin directory (as you mention in a comment to the other answer)
- Choose a proper location elsewhere on the disk
- Look up how to write a DownloadServlet. That servlet can deliver the uploaded content, e.g. at `http://example.com/image/FILENAME.jpg`
- Look up "path traversal", so that you don't make yourself vulnerable to this type of attack: `http://example.com/image/../../../../etc/passwd`